# FBML Canvas Application Authentication

Tags: php, facebook, fbml, facebook-graph-api

I'm modifying an FBML canvas app to use the new PHP SDK and authentication instead of the old REST api.

Right now I'm attempting to use this snippet:

```
$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_birthday, publish_stream, email'));
    header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
}
```

However if I use the php header function for any URL that isn't relative, I get this error:

```
Application Temporarily Unavailable
The URL [https://www.facebook.com/login.php?.........] is not valid.

Sorry, the application you were using is experiencing a problem. Please try again later.
```

If I need to have authentication on my FBML canvas app using the latest PHP SDK, how do I properly redirect to the app login page that requests the extended permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you cannot use a server side redirect (header()) to push user to the auth page. I'm using this at the moment:

```
function redirect($url)
{
    echo '<script>top.location="' . $url . '";</script>';
    //echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $url . '"></fb:redirect>';
    //header("location:$url");
    exit();
}
```